# Summarising a Research Paper

Tags: proof-writing, education, article-writing, research

I thought to put this out to the community. I am an Undergraduate student summarising maths papers, firstly to get to grips with reading mathematical research and collecting a body of interesting research papers for myself.

Secondly, I would like to eventually do a Postgrad in Mathematics and I want to start reading mathematics papers from now as this is a key part of postgraduate mathematics .

I have found a couple of papers I understand and would like to review, One is based on the Chebychev inequality and the other is an econometrics paper.

I have read both throughly and I feel I can summarise them.

Where I am confused is whether or not to write the theorems the Mathematicians use in the summaries? Is this plagiarism if the theorems are  attributed to the author?

Secondly, Do you put proofs in the summaries? For papers that are proof heavy, I was thinking of stating the beginning and end of the proofs, something along these lines:

The author begins with Problem A: 1+1=2
and concludes with F:             1=2-1

Therefore proving the theorem that 1+1=2.for all 1 on the Real line. (Pythagoras et al 2020)

****** Please note the example above is just an example and I am aware that It is not a real proof /theorem.******

I was just wondering if the format  is OK in a summary paper?

Do I attribute the summary to my name?

Do Summaries have to be typed in Latex? I currently use the Math function in word .

Any other tips will be greatly appreciated.
A

Comment: I’m confused about the nature of these “summaries” you’re writing. Is it meant to be submitted/posted somewhere, or is it just for your own learning?

Comment: Thank you, The nature of the summaries are two fold, I do intend to post them to an online wiki/blog in the end. Secondly to build a body of research summaries that I can dip into myself when I go into postgraduate school.

Comment: At this point in your eduction, I think it is more fruitful to absorb as many mathematics as you can rather than reading research papers.

Comment: It's not plagiarism if you cite and credit the source.